# ERROR: syntax error at or near "(" when creating a new table

Tags: postgresql

I am extremely new to PostgreSQL and every time I try to create a new table, I run into the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "(" LINE 1: ..." ("id_azucarusuario" 
   SERIAL, "id_usuario" integer(128) NOT ...
```

Here is the SQL for the table I am trying to define:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."usuario_azucar" 
( "id_azucarusuario" SERIAL,
  "id_usuario" integer(128) NOT NULL, 
  "codigogeneral" character varying(240) NOT NULL, 
  "razonsocial" character(240), 
  "nombrecomercial" character(240), 
  "nit" integer(128), 
  "nummatricula" integer(128),
  "direccionempresa" character(240), 
  "subdepartamento" character(240),
  "subciudad" character(240), 
  "subdireccion" character varying(240),
  "subcalle" character varying(240), 
  "subreferencia" character varying(240), 
  "subtelefono" integer(128), 
  "subpagweb" character(240),
  "subemail" character varying(240), 
  "rai" character varying(240),
  "descripcion_proceso_azucar" character varying(240),
  "descripcion_proceso_alcohol" character varying(240),
  "balance_energeticoomasic" character varying(240),
  "productos_obtenidos" character varying(240), 
  "capacidad_azuoalco" character varying(240), 
  "capacidadreal_azuoalcoho" character varying(240), 
  PRIMARY KEY ("id_azucarusuario")
) 
WITHOUT OIDS;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no type as `integer(...)`, choose `smallint`, `integer` or `bigint` given the ranges here:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html

Comment: And while you're at it, switch all your textual columns to `text`. `character(240)` will pad your string with spaces to the width of 240 characters, which is rarely useful, and `character varying` has no real advantage in Postgres, and is just a (usually arbitrary) maximum length constraint (unless you want increased portability to other DBMSes). See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html

Answer (score 0):

**Do not use any reserved keywords..**

You must change the table name from '**public**' to something else.. as it is a reserved keyword on postgresql..

[Here is a link for reserved keywords in postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html)